# Verificar se já existe na tabela antes de inserir registro

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso incluir um registro em uma tabela, no entanto antes da inclusão para não ocorrer duplicidade é necessário fazer uma verificação.

Como tenho uma coluna `ID` com tendo como propriedade `AUTO INCREMENT`, não consigo usar o `INSERT IGNORE INTO`.

#### Tabela

```
CREATE TABLE relacao (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_1 varchar(24) NOT NULL,
    user_2 varchar(24) NOT NULL
)
```

#### Exemplo

```
INSERT INTO relacao(user_1, user_2) values("Pedro", "Laura")
INSERT INTO relacao(user_1, user_2) values("Pedro", "Laura") /* não deixar inserir*/
```

Como seria a `query` para verificar se existe ou não o registro antes da inserção?

Comment: Você vai inserir os dados direto no mysql, ou vai usar algum script para isso?

Comment: @LeoLetto De preferência que a verificação seja diretamente no MySQL. Exemplo: Se não existir: insere, senão: não faça nada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode fazer o `INSERT` direto de uma `query`.

```
INSERT INTO relacao(user_1, user_2) 
SELECT x.user_1, x.user_2 
  FROM (SELECT 'Pedro' user_1, 'Laura' user_2) x
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM relacao r 
                   WHERE r.user_1 = x.user_1
                     AND r.user_2 = x.user_2)
```

Comment: Ola Sorack, deu erro de sintaxe nos dois casos.

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS funciona no MySQL?

Comment: Versão 5.7.14...

Comment: ERROR: "Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT..."

Comment: Beleza, sem problema.

Comment: Deu um erro aqui ainda, talvez por causa do `SELECT FROM`. Coloquei `SELEC 1 FROM`.
Seguindo seu raciocínio, consegui resolver o problema desta forma:

`INSERT INTO relacao(user_1, user_2)
SELECT a.user_1,
       a.user_2
FROM (SELECT 'Pedro' user_1, 'Laura' user_2) a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                   FROM relacao
                   WHERE user_1 = 'Pedro'
                     AND user_2= 'Laura')`

Se quiser alterar ai, dou os créditos pra ti. Obrigado

Comment: o retorno dessa adição seria 'true' para ambos os casos (existindo ou não) teria como controlar esse retorno?

Answer (score 3):

Usando o numero do ID você pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
   REPLACE INTO relacao VALUES ( 1, 'Pedro', 'Laura' )
```

Se não existir o id 1 ele irá inserir o registro e se existir
ele fará o update.

Comment: Esta é a melhor resposta.

Comment: @TiagoLuz acho que vocês estão enganado. o identificador é `autoincrement`, quando faço um `INSERT`, eu não passo o ID.

Comment: No caso a pergunta não cita se ele guarda esse valor após a inserção, então a sua resposta é apenas parcial. Você pode tentar incrementá-la mostrando como pode pegar o último `ID` inserido para usar na sua solução

Comment: @seamusd sim, verdade.. não tinha visto isso. Mas você tem outra opção para usar o replace .... remover a chave primária  autoincrement ID e colocar user_1 e user_2 como chave primária composta. Aí o replace funciona perfeitamente, e acredito que com uma performance melhor do que solução proposta. Abraço e boa sorte! =)